# Why are Kylo Ren and Rey evenly matched in Force pulling in TLJ?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren, rey

In *The Force Awakens*, Kylo tries to take Luke's lightsaber from the ground but Rey is able to pull it away from him with the Force.

In *The Last Jedi*,

> Rey tries to use the Force to steal the lightsaber from Kylo but he fights her for it and they break it.

By all logic, Kylo should've been stronger in *The Force Awakens* than Rey and so should've been able to get the lightsaber from her then.  But then in *The Last Jedi*, where Rey has trained and should be stronger, they seem to be equally matched.

**Is there a reason for this?**

Comment: What logic says that he should be _stronger_? Luke even says about her: "I've seen this kind of raw power once before, and it didn't scare me enough then. It does now."

Comment: @dvk Which is why Kylo Ren takes on 3-4 Pratorian Guards and Rey struggles with one. And why Finn handily defeats Phasma. Clearly, the men of Star Wars are very oppressed.

Comment: @RogueJedi - sarcasm is sarcastic. And a bunch of LSG people are on formal record stating they tried to woke TGFFA.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate of the current target. That question asks about Kylo Ren being able to move the lightsaber _at all_, while this question asks about a comparison of strength of Force use of Kylo Ren vs Rey.

Comment: @SQB The question boils down to the same in each case "Why couldn't Kylo move the lightsaber in TFA but could in TLJ?" They just approach it from a different angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that Rey doesn't appear to be any stronger in TLJ than she was in TFA. Luke gives her no formal training and she wouldn't have had time to

> read the Jedi Temple books

We also don't see Kylo Ren doing any real training either. I don't think training played much, if any, role in this.

What we see in TFA is a Kylo Ren who has been shot and wounded. As powerful as he is in TLJ, he should have been easily able to get the lightsaber out of the snow, but we watch him struggle to do so. In fact, you could argue that it was Rey, not he, who actually pulled it out of the snow. You'll note he doesn't try to take it away from her using The Force either.

Comment: I concur.  Kylo Ren got an unknown amount of training from Luke who was mostly self-taught (Degoba was what.. a week?  two?).  And Kylo Ren's sith master was (wisely) a big talking head hologram.  Kylo's sword training seems to consist of raging out on elevator consoles and local machinery.  Calling Kylo raw and untrained is completely feasible.

Answer (score 5):

In **The Force Awakening**, Kylo Ren

- is surprised by The Force awakening in Rey
- is weakened by his internal struggle

  > to kill his father and subsequent bowcaster wound inflicted by Chewbacca

In the next movie, Kylo Ren is prepared to meet Rey as a strong opponent, not some scavenger girl from a worthless planet.

Comment: Also in TFA they were pulling in the same direction not against. Probably played some part in it